# Wrong colors on LCD connected to thin mini ITX

Tags: lcd

So, basically I have a 15.6" LCD panel and I've hooked it up to a motherboard's LVDS header. Everything is kind of working - image is there, but its colors are strange. I tested the panel with pure Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta and Yellow and it displays these 6 colors accurately. The problem comes when I try to mix them up in some other color or use shade of that color - e.g. Dark Red is shown as Blue, Indigo as Red, 50% Gray as pure white.

**What I have done so far:**
(1) Connected the LCD to Motherboard - in the proper way i think, correct me if I'm wrong. (2) Selected 1920x1080 48bit option in BIOS - the only one it is working with (3) Switched the polarity of Clock pairs, Data pairs and both Clock and Data together - In all cases LCD just went black and stayed like this, which is normal i guess.
(4) Then switched them back again as they were in the first place - colors were still mixed up. 
(5) Created .INF file containing LCD's EDID configuration and overrode the default in Windows (which was wrong anyway - there is no way it can read that data from EEPROM itself) - yet no improvement.

LCD is Innolux N156HGE-LB1

Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-H100TN-M

Here is how I connected LCD to LVDS header on motherboard:[image]

I have sent a ticket to Gigabyte's tech support, but I've lost hope that they will even check it anytime soon, so any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Here is what i get as a result: [Results](http://imgur.com/a/kQai1)

Comment: This is motherboard's user manual - [GA-H110TN-M](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-h110tn-series_e.pdf)

Comment: This is LCD's datasheet - [Innolux N156HGE-LB1](http://recomit.de/service_manuals/N156HGE-LB1_C1.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that the display and motherboard are compatible - there are no common standards when it comes to LCD panels, they tend to vary in colour formatting, number of lanes, etc.

Looking at the datasheet it seems your display is an 18bit colour version. The colours are not split out into lanes (i.e. there isn't one lane for Red, one for Green, one for Blue), but rather are interleaved in a weird format. This is probably where you are having issues.

If I had to hazard a guess, the options for 24bit and 48bit are designed for displays with 24bit colour and one lane per colour. The 48bit is probably representative of using the 6 lanes (odd/even), whereas 24bit will use 3 lanes.

In both cases the colour formatting probably does not match what your display is expecting, and hence you get weird bleeding between the colours. My guess is when you do the solid colours, what you are seeing is not actually pure Red/Green/Blue blocks, which you can probably confirm by taking a macro shot of the pixels (e.g. you'll likely see the green dimly lit for your red bar).

You can see in the list that there are some options for 18bit, which will likely use just the odd lanes with the colours interleaved correctly. There are seemingly no options for 36bit which is what your display will require (18bit over odd/even lanes).

Unless Gigabyte have or release a firmware update to support your display, you are unfortunately out of luck. Try to find a 24bit LCD panel rather than an 18bit panel.

---

Of course this is just speculation, but I've had some experience with the embedded VGA connectors on Mini ITX boards having weird colours depending on the settings and the display.